# Progress event for TAzureBlobService and TAmazonStorageService

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy10

When uploading or downloading data to the cloud services (using TAzureBlobService or TAmazonStorageService), there doesn't appear to be any way to get feedback on the upload/download progress.

I can see that eventually TIdTCPClientCustom.Connect is called, and in that function it creates a default IOHandler for the connection if one doesn't exist (and it doesn't unless SSL is used). If I could set the OnWorkBegin, OnWorkEnd, and OnWork events for that IOHandler then I could track the progress, but there's no way I can see to do that.

If an SSL connection is used, then an IOHandler is created (e.g. in TAzureBlobService.PrepareRequest), but the IOHandler is an interface and has no OnWorkBegin etc. properties.

I think the solution is to create a class descended from TAzureBlobService or TAmazonStorageService, then override the PrepareRequest method. In that I can get access to the TCloudHTTP instance (as it is created in PrepareRequest), and from that I can get access to IOHandler. But how do I create that IOHandler (as it is defined as an interface) and set the events (which aren't part of that interface) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `OnWork` events are exposed by `TIdComponent`, which both `TIdCustomTCPClient` and `TIdIOHandler` derive from.  `TIdIOHandler` is not an interface.

Internally, `TIdCustomTCPClient` hooks into the `OnWork` events of whatever `IOHandler` is assigned to it.  You should assign your event handlers to the `OnWork` events provided by `TIdCustomTCPClient`, not `TIdIOHandler` directly.  Then it will not matter what kind of `IOHandler` gets assigned at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I've figured it out now. In my replacement PrepareRequest function I simply set the work events using (Result.Peer.GetObject as TIdTCPClientCustom).OnWorkBegin:=abc, for example. The Result of PrepareRequest is TCloudHTTP.